# How Do I Get Constant Animation Speed?

Tags: jquery

How Do I Get Constant Animation Speed?
`$( "#progress20").animate({"width": "0"}, 40000);`

https://jsfiddle.net/wahL4tbs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bootstrap progress bars, which [**have their own animations**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress) supplied via CSS.

> **Cross-browser compatibility**
>   Progress bars use CSS3 transitions and animations to achieve some of their effects. These features are not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and below or 
>   older versions of Firefox. Opera 12 does not support animations.

You should not be attempting to use jQuery's `animate` to animate the changing Bootstraps progress bar. Just set the new value and let CSS animations do their job, or avoid the use of Bootstrap's progress bars and code your own. The styling is very trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The default `easing` for [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) is `"swing"`

> **easing** (default: `swing`)

Set `"linear"` at `easing` option

```
$("#progress20").animate({"width": "0%"}, 40000, "linear");
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wahL4tbs/2/

Comment: @cale_b No, `"swing"` is default easing

Comment: Would be good to mention that the default is "swing" so you have to set it to linear.

Comment: @eska97 Not certain what image is attempting to depict ?

Comment: @guest271314
`$("#progress20").animate({
  "width": "0%"
}, 40000, "linear");`
not working

`$("#progress20").animate({"width": "0"}, 40000, "linear");`
after 20sec of 40sec is on 75% of width

Comment: @eska97 Bootstrap appears to be at fault. See https://jsfiddle.net/wahL4tbs/3/ for an identical implementation without Bootstrap's CSS fowling things up.